# Refurbished iPhone 4 won't send SMS

Tags: iphone, sms

I recently purchased a refurbished iPhone 4. I trimmed my sim card to make it a micro-SIM and installed it into the phone. I can make calls and receive SMS, but I'm unable to send SMS. What could be the problem and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Go to **Settings > Messages** and see if **iMessage** is on. If it is, then make sure **Send as SMS** is also on. If not, every time you send a message, it would try to send it as an iMessage, which needs Internet connectivity to go through Apple. Once you've checked this, add a comment (below this one) or edit your question appropriately.

Comment: ok tried that but now I can only send to people that imessage.....would it have anything to do with the sim card that I cut down to size?

Comment: No, you should be able to send messages to anyone. If it tries sending as iMessage, tap and hold the message until the "Send as Text Message" prompt appears and select it.

Comment: tried taking sim out and rebooting...now getting SOS messages